# GeoServer + PostGIS: multiple tables or SLD filters

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I'm setting up a PostGIS and GeoServer for OpenLayers use and started wondering how to achieve the best performance in selecting and rendering the geometries.

Is it better to create multiple tables / materialized views to the database and then create layers and styles for each, and not use filters in the SLDs, or should all the data be dumped on a single table and then use SLD filters for applying the styles? And if SLD filters are the way to go, should I have multiple `FeatureTypeStyle`s with one `Rule` each, or multiple `Rule`s in single `FeatureTypeStyle`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way for this to not be *opinion-based* would be to try it all ways with your dataset and compile statistics on the performance.

Comment: Yeah, naturally would need to benchmark different options. I was hoping there would be some generic guideline which way to go though, but I understand that it of course does vary with the dataset.

Comment: Depends on what your data, What you want to do?

Comment: City map with `MaxScaleDenominator` of 500k and smaller, ie. buildings, roads, parks, water areas etc. No big geometries.